# By default AuthComponent uses FormAuthenticate

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I try to use the function FormAuthenticate used in the identify function in the AuthComponent class to check the user and password in the database, but it seems the AuthComponenent class doesn't use it by default

Do i have to make some settings to use the FormAuthenticate function ?

Regards

Frank

Answer (score 0):

It should be using `Form` by default, but if you want to force it use this when you add `Auth` to `$components`:

```
public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array('Form')
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems there is still a problem. First: Do i have to override the auth component in cake/app/controller/component or can i use the one in cake/lib/cake/controller/component ?

Comment: You don't need to override anything. Maybe you should post the code you're using to include `Auth` and how you're trying to generate a form, and I can take a look at that.

Comment: the function login in UsersController                               public function login() {  
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
    }

Comment: Where did you put the code I have in my answer? It should be in the AppController, is that where you have it?

Comment: In the AppController:                                          public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array('Form')
));

Comment: I think it comes from the password encryption because i see in the sql query that the password is not the same than in the database

Comment: I see. Are you using an old database that was already set up before? Or are you adding new users yourself?